# Oracle transpose a simple table

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I have a simple table from a select query that looks like this

```
CATEGORY   | EQUAL | LESS  | GREATER
VALUE      |  60   |  100  |    20
```

I want to be able to transpose it so it looks like this

```
CATEGORY | VALUE
EQUAL    | 60
LESS     | 100
GREATER  | 20
```

I tried using the pivot function in oracle but I can't seem to get it to work.
I've tried looking all over online but I can't find anything that will help me.
Any help is much appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select 'EQUAL' as category, equal as value from t union all
select 'LESS' as category, less from t union all
select 'GREATER' as category, greater from t;
```

If you had a large table, you might want to try some other method (such as a lateral join in Oracle 12c).  But for a small table, this is fine.

Comment: This was the simplest solution and it worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Using unpivot -

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (CATEGORY varchar2(5), EQUAL int, LESS int, GREATER int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 (CATEGORY, EQUAL, LESS, GREATER)
         VALUES ('VALUE', 60, 100, 20)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

Query -

```
select COL AS CATEGORY,VALUE from table1
unpivot (value for COL in (EQUAL, LESS, GREATER));
```

Result -

```
CATEGORY    VALUE
EQUAL       60
LESS        100
GREATER     20
```

Answer (score 1):

You may unpivot your values by contribution of *DECODE* and *CONNECT BY* clauses :

```
select decode(myId, 1, 'EQUAL',
                    2, 'LESS',
                    3, 'GREATER') as category,
       decode(myId, 1, EQUAL,
                    2, LESS,
                    3, GREATER) as value
  from mytable
   cross join (select level as myId from dual connect by level <= 3);

  CATEGORY  VALUE
  --------  -----
  EQUAL       60
  LESS       100
  GREATER     20
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0a6e894/33)